# Unable to find the element in a Salesforce search results

Tags: java, selenium

I have searched for an Account in Salesforce and it gives a few search results. But I'm unable to find the element in Selenium.

I have tried using absolute/relative `xpath` and `CSSSelector`, `LinkText` as well.

Used: `driver.findElement(By.linkText("ILT_Order1")).click();`

```html
<a href="javascript:srcUp(%27%2F0010C000003HmzI%3FsrPos%3D0%26srKp%3D001%26isdtp%3Dvw%27);" data-seclke="Account" data-seclkh="b2e6250471c982c9bec58d55cc1e0f42" data-seclki="0010C000003HmzI" data-seclkp="/0010C000003HmzI" data-seclkr="1" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)">ILT_Order1</a>
```

I am unable to find the element.

Answer (score 1):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable` and following xpath.
If still not found then check if there any `iframe` available on the page.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@data-seclke='Account'][text()='ILT_Order1']")));
element.click()
```

Comment: How do I check if the page is an iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

As the element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you need to use `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("ILT_Order1"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[data-seclke='Account'][onmousedown^='searchResultClick'][href]"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@data-seclke='Account' and text()='ILT_Order1'][starts-with(@onmousedown, 'searchResultClick')]"))).click();
  ```